Operating systems boot
I have several operating systems installed on my computer and when I had Ubuntu 22.04 it recognized all of them in the boot starting page and offered me the choice between them; but when I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 it does not allow for other OS but itself and it does not offer any choices in the boot-up starting page. Is there a way to solve this?.
crostrogarcia@gmail.com

Which OS controls your boot process (ie. it's grub or whatever you're using is being shown) as maybe that was changed and you just need to revert it. At grub 2.06 there was a change to Grub's defaults that made multi-boots require manual setup by default; but a re-install will trigger that & not release-upgrade; but I'd still check your OS_PROBER setting.

In /etc/default/grub do your have this? GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true  or is it FALSE. If false, run sudo update-grub
